# CSS - How to get star aligned properly on this page

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having difficulty with IE 9 and Opera Browsers only for the alignment of a star.

I am using the following HTML:

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="floatleft star">&#9733;</div>
    <h3 class="icontxt">Co-Hosts</h3>
</div>
```

The Following CSS:

```
.floatleft
{
    float: left;
}

.fullwidth
{
    width: 100%;
}

h3
{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "GearedSlab-Regular", "Geared Slab Regular", "geared_slabregular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #212D3B;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

h3.icontxt
{
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.star
{
    font-size: 1.4em !important;
    color: #A92A23;
}
```

Ok, so Chrome, Firefox, and Safari render it like so (the way I need it in all browsers to be):

[image: This looks exactly the way I need it to look]

However, if you look at this in IE 9, and/or Opera, it looks like this:

[image: The Star is too high]

The Star is too high, it needs to be in line with the text:  "CO-HOSTS"

Am I doing something wrong here?  How can this be done for IE, Chrome, Opera, Safari, and Firefox universally?  This is just so frustrating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How about this](http://jsfiddle.net/EcHeZ/):

```
.floatleft
{
    float: left;
}

.fullwidth
{
    width: 100%;
}

h3
{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "GearedSlab-Regular", "Geared Slab Regular", "geared_slabregular";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #212D3B;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

h3.icontxt
{
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.star
{
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-size: 1.4em !important;
    color: #A92A23;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling after I wrote this that it was the `line-height` on the `h3` element that was screwing this up!  Now it is great!  Thanks for reinforcing this, OMG, was about to use jQuery to remedy this situation too... so glad I didn't go down that route!

Comment: That's it... in fact, you don't need the vertical-align: middle or the !important.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this.  The `line-height` does it perfectly!!  Thanks so much guys!  But I changed the `line-height` to `1.6em` cause it looks better to me for some reason.  Maybe because the `.star` font-size is only `1.4em` which is `.1em` less than the `h3` element.

Comment: It's always the small things that get ya in the end!